# Can someone help me distinguish these confusing words? Thank you

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I am very confused about the **meaning** and **use** of these words: proportional, in proportion to, pro rata, and rateable.

Could you give me some common sense of these words so that I can distinguish them. If possible, please show me some examples for better understanding.

Thank you all.

Comment: I can help you with two of them-Proportional- weight of a body is proportional to its mass. <br/> In proportion to- Today's homework is very less in proportion to what was given yesterday

Comment: You need to tell us whether you have looked up the words in a dictionary and what you understand from the definitions you found.

Comment: Yes, I checked these words in the dictionary. But for me, an English learner, the literal meaning of these words are very similar. I hope to know how native speakers use these words in daily life, so I can follow your interpretation.

Comment: We should always ask ourselves , what is my question before we ask something. Then the question reaches everyone in the right form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Proportional*** is an adjective that means "corresponding in size or amount to something else." Thus, if today's homework is less than yesterday's, then *proportionally* it is less than yesterday's. (@Ajay Tyagi: You use *very* to give emphasis to a superlative adjective or adverb, so you wouldn't say 'very less;' the correct usage would be 'very much less,' if you're trying to emphasize the difference.)

***In proportion to*** is a phrase using *proportion*, which can be a noun meaning 'a part, share, or number considered in comparative relation to a whole,' or as a verb meaning 'adjust or regulate (something) so that it has a particular or suitable relationship to something else; related in size, number, or amount to (something else).' It essentially means the same thing as *proportional.* *His head is large in proportion to his body.*

***Pro rata*** is an adjective or adverb which literally translates from Latin as "for calculation," and in modern English usage essentially means "in proportion to an exactly calculated value." It refers to a process where whatever is being allocated will be distributed in equal portions. If something is given out to people on a pro rata basis, it means assigning an amount to one person according to their share of the whole. So, if ten people each own 10% of an investment, they will each receive 10% of any return. If one person owns 19% and the rest each own 9%, then a pro rata distribution will return 19% to the largest shareholder and 9% each to the rest.
*The profits will be shared on a pro rata basis.*

***Ratable*** is an adjective that refers to a something on which an appraisal or estimate is possible. For example, a farm is a ratable property because its value is able to be assessed.

As a professional estimator, I use the latter two often, and for very specific reasons. In informal speech or writing, or situations requiring less precision, I would use 'proportional,' or 'in proportion to.'

Here are some links:

[Wikipedia: Pro Rata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_rata)

[Merriam Webster: Ratable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ratable)

[Merriam Webster: Proportional](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proportion)

[Merriam Webster: In Proportion To](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20proportion%20to)

Comment: Thanks for the correction .